# Activerecord migration error on postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a error without explanation.

**My error :**

```
G::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "conjoncture_index_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "reports" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_c25ad9a112"
FOREIGN KEY ("conjoncture_index_id")
  REFERENCES "conjoncture_indices" ("id")
```

**My migration :**

```
class AddColumnToReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :reports, :conjoncture_indice, index: true
    add_foreign_key :reports, :conjoncture_indices
  end
end
```

**My create table migration :**

```
class CreateConjonctureIndices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :conjoncture_indices do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.float :value

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**My model :**

```
class ConjonctureIndice < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reports
    by_star_field :date
end
```

**My ConjonctureIndice shema.rb part :**

```
  create_table "conjoncture_indices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "date"
    t.float    "value"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  end
```

I'm looking for "conjoncture_index" in my project but nothing... I think that a old version of the project uses "conjoncture_index" instead "conjoncture_indice" but all occurence are deleted.

Comment: Can you post the schema.rb of the ConjonctureIndice part

Comment: I fear that the naming is indeed the problem , apart from that everything looks ok . Can you rename and check it ?

Comment: Just name it Conjoncture and remove the index and indice part

Comment: I rename all occurence of ConjonctureIndice to Conjoncture and always the same error "G::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "confidence_index_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist"

Comment: Is there a kind of cache for activerecord ? He would use for migration ... Because in my project there is nowhere refers to this "index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the problem. i think that the error message is the same as before but he refer to a other table called "confidence_indices". The error come from "indice" word.. when i delete it i have no problem.

Comment: Glad  you were able to find it .

Answer (score 5):

In rails , The migration names are plural whereas the model names are singular . So the model name should had been Index but it cannot be as it's a reserved keyword , the plural of which transforms to ConjunctureIndices .

Note - If you are still in doubt , then you can drop and re-create the database but i suspect the naming convention to be an issue in your case .

Comment: Rename and migrate again , let me know what happens then